# Update time portion of a datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a DateTime variable in SQL Server..I have the below code to check for weekend and then subtract the days to make it Friday. Now I also want to set the time of this new Datetime as 5 PM on the Friday. Can someone please tell me how can I achieve this.

```
if(DATENAME(DW, @EndDate) = 'Sunday')
Begin
Set @EndDate = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -2, @EndDate))
End
if(DATENAME(DW, @EndDate) = 'Saturday')
Begin
Set @EndDate = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate))
End
End
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add 17 hours:

```
Set @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 17, DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate))
```

I have no idea why you have phrased this logic using a subquery.  It is not necessary.

If your data already has a time component, then cast to a `date` first to get rid of the time component, then back to a `datetime`:

```
Set @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 17, DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate))))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon..I have the date in datetime format ..doing select  DATEADD(HOUR, 17, DATEADD(DAY, -1, '03/17/2019 12:08:08')) leads to 2019-03-17 05:08:08.000 I was looking for 03/15/2019 17:00:00

Comment: Awesome..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select cast(CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE()) + '17:00' as datetime)